# llenar un textbox usando una consulta c#

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio

hola estoy necesitando obtener un resultado espesifico desde una consulta a una base de datos y ese resultado mostrarlo en un text box y no logro hacerlo funcionar.

```
OleDbConnection cnx = new OleDbConnection("Provider=VFPOLEDB.1;Data Source=D:\\tabla");
            try
            {
                cnx.Open();
                OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
                command.Connection = cnx;
                string query = "select max(id) from datos";
                command.CommandText = query;
                OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                   ACA NO SE COMO HACER PARA MOSTRAR EL RESULTADO DE LA CONSULTA EN EL TEXTBOX
                }
                cnx.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error " + ex);
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como tu **consulta SQL** solo devuelve una fila no te hace falta el **ciclo while**, por tanto podrías hacer lo siguiente:

```
if (reader.Read())
{
   textBox1.Text = reader["Maximo"] .ToString();
}
```

Aquí se pregunta si la consulta devolvió alguna fila, y de cumplirse esta condición se guarda en el **textBox** el campo que deseamos.

Te recomiendo que en tu **consulta SQL** uses un alias para que el nombre del campo sea más descriptivo:

```
string query = "select max(id) as Maximo from datos";
```

Como ves aquí se le da el **alias de Maximo** para referirse al mayor id, que es el dato que devuelves en tu consulta.